# NVD3 Toggle Streams

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Does anyone know how to disable a stream after drawing?

I'm looking to modify the active streams after the page has loaded, and the user has clicked on a button in a different part of the page.

I've been working on code to simulate a click event after it determines it's state, but that seems kind of clunky and slow.

**EDIT:**
As requested, here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/p4x0c8f8/) of an NVD3 chart with multiple streams (data series found in the legend).

After chart render, I am looking for a function that can enable / disable multiple streams (data 0, data 1, etc. on the example) in a single call.

I was working on something that dispatches click events to the labels, but thought there must be a better way.

```
<div id="chart">
    <svg></svg>
</div>
```

---

```
var data = function() {
  return stream_layers(4,10+Math.random()*10,.1).map(function(data, i) {
    return {
      key: 'Data ' + i,
      values: data
    };
  });
}

function stream_layers(n, m, o) {
    if (arguments.length < 3) o = 0;

    function bump(a) {
        var x = 1 / (.1 + Math.random()),
            y = 2 * Math.random() - .5,
            z = 10 / (.1 + Math.random());
        for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            var w = (i / m - y) * z;
            a[i] += x * Math.exp(-w * w);
        }
    }
    return d3.range(n).map(function () {
        var a = [],
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) a[i] = o + o * Math.random();
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) bump(a);
        return a.map(stream_index);
    });
}

function stream_index(d, i) {
    return {
        x: i,
        y: Math.max(0, d)
    };
}

nv.addGraph(function () {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();

    chart.multibar.stacked(false);
    chart.showControls(false);
    chart.showLegend(true);
    chart.reduceXTicks(false);

    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(data())
        .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean? Also include a JSFiddle/Plunkr with your current code.

Comment: @jeznag done. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer..

The following works

```
chartData[i].disabled = true; // chartData = original data object fed to NVD3 chart
chartData[i].userDisabled = true;
chart.update(); // chart = a reference to your NVD3 chart instance.
```